# How to obtain te most frequent routes from historical data?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have the following data in Hive 1.2.1 (my real data set is much bigger, but the data structure is similar):

```
id    radar_id     car_id     datetime
1     A21          123        2017-03-08 17:31:19.0
2     A21          555        2017-03-08 17:32:00.0
3     A21          777        2017-03-08 17:33:00.0
4     B15          123        2017-03-08 17:35:22.0
5     B15          555        2017-03-08 17:34:05.0
6     B15          777        2017-03-08 20:50:12.0
7     C09          777        2017-03-08 20:55:00.0
8     A21          123        2017-03-09 11:00:00.0
9     C11          664        2017-03-09 11:10:00.0
10    A21          123        2017-03-09 11:12:00.0
11    A21          555        2017-03-09 11:12:10.0
12    B15          123        2017-03-09 11:14:00.0
13    B15          555        2017-03-09 11:20:00.0
14    A21          444        2017-03-09 10:00:00.0
15    C09          444        2017-03-09 10:20:00.0
16    B15          444        2017-03-09 10:05:00.0
```

I want to get top 2 of the most frequent routes. A route is a sequence of `radar_id` ordered by `datetime`. I would like to get the result as follows:

```
route          frequency
A21->B15       2
A21->B15-C09   1
```

The frequency is the average number of times that vehicles (non-unique, no need to consider `car_id`) passed by a route per day.
For the route `A21->B15` the frequency is 2, because there are 3 rides on `2017-03-08` and 1 ride on `2017-03-09`. It is important that the vehicle `123` did a route `A21->A21->B15` on date `2017-03-09`. It is not the same as `A21->B15`. So, I want to consider routes from the initial radar until the final radar that captured that vehicle during the day.

The cases when a ride begins at 23:55 and finishes at 00:22 should be considered as two different routes.

How can I do it using Hive 1.2.1?

**Update:**

As suggested in the answers, I tested this query, but `route` does not contain `->`. The values of route look like `000021` or `0450001`, etc.

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select      regexp_replace(route,'(?<=^|->)\\d{5}','')  as route " +
                                      ",count(*) / min(days)                        as frequency " +

                           "from       (select      concat_ws('->',sort_array(collect_list(radarids))) as route " +
                                                  ",count(distinct dt) over()                           as days " +
                                       "from       (select  car_id " +
                                                  ",to_date(datetime)   as dt " +
                                                  ",concat(printf('%05d',row_number() over " +
                                                  "(partition by car_id,to_date(datetime) " +
                                                  "order by to_unix_timestamp(datetime))),cast(radarid as string)) as radarids " +
                                                  "from    mytable " +
                                                  ") t " +
                                       "group by    car_id " +
                                      ",dt " +
                                      ") t " +
                           "group by    route " +      
                           "order by    frequency desc " +
                           "limit       5")
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify when a radar is considered to be "final"? The car 777 was captured by A21, B15 and C09 radars on 2017-03-08. Should it be "A21->B15" or "A21->B15->C09" (then "A21->B15" frequency during that day is not 3 as you say, but 2)? It's a little bit confusing because after that you say that "A21->A21->B15" should not be considered as "A21->A21" route.

Comment: Also, it would be better if you provide the exact DDL (schema) of the table so it's known what is `datetime` type, is the table partitioned (by `datetime` I guess), etc.

Comment: You have only 3 `A21->B15` routes

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: Yes, I have three `A21->B15` routes on `2017-03-08` and one `A21->B15` route on `2017-03-09`. So, the average between these two days should be (3+1)/2=2.

Comment: No, the route of car `777` on `2017-03-08` is `A21->B15->C09`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select      regexp_replace(route,'(?<=^|->)\\d{5}','')  as route
           ,count(*) / min(days)                        as frequency

from       (select      concat_ws('->',sort_array(collect_list(radar_ids))) as route
                       ,count(distinct dt) over()                           as days
            from       (select  car_id
                               ,to_date(datetime)   as dt
                               ,concat(printf('%05d',row_number() over (partition by car_id,to_date(datetime) order by datetime)),radar_id) as radar_ids
                        from    mytable
                        ) t
            group by    car_id
                       ,dt
            ) t
group by    route          
order by    frequency desc
limit       2 
;
```

---

```
+---------------+-----------+
| route         | frequency |
+---------------+-----------+
| A21->B15      | 1.5       |
+---------------+-----------+
| A21->B15->C09 | 1.0       |
+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: +1. I haven't thought about using `concat` + window function instead of nested subquery with `SORT BY`, which would result in 5 jobs instead of 4 (your example).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Did you use my input data? How did you get 1.5 for `A21->B15`? Shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: Yes, I have used your data. See my comment to your post.

Comment: Also how can I separate radar ids with `->`? I see that in your output the ids are separated.

Comment: When I run this query on my data, I get `route` like this `0000121` For some reason, `->` separator is not applied.

Comment: Hmm. May it be related because of different versions of Hive that we use?

Comment: @Dinosaurius - Unlikely. Your actual data is probably different somehow from your sample data.

Comment: The only difference is that `radar_id` is integer, `car_id` is string and `datetime` is string. So, I used `cast(radar_id as string)`. See my update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151259/discussion-between-dudu-markovitz-and-dinosaurius).

Comment: So you have supplied a data sample that does not reflect your actual data. The given solution works for the sample data but not for the actual data. What exactly do you expect to happen at this point?

Answer (score 1):

It seems from the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual) that HIVE doesn't support recursive CTE, but luckily it supports subqueries, `group by` clasue, `row_number` analytic funtion, `trunc(string date, string format)` function, `concat` function and `LIMIT x` clause.
I don't have access to Hive, but I can show how to build such a query on PostgreSQL, there are only minor differences between them so I belive You manage to rewrite it. I think that the only thing to replace is `date_trunc('day', datetim )` function from postgres with `trunc(datetim , 'DD')` from Hive.

```
SELECT route, avg( cnt ) as average
FROM (
        SELECT concat(route1, '>', route2, '>', route3, '>', route4) as Route,
               count(*) as cnt
        FROM (
                SELECT date_trunc('day', datetim ) As datetim, car_id,
                    max( case when rn = 1 then radar_id end ) as route1,
                    max( case when rn = 2 then radar_id end ) as route2,
                    max( case when rn = 3 then radar_id end ) as route3,
                    max( case when rn = 4 then radar_id end ) as route4
                /*  max( case when rn = 5 then radar_id end ) as route5
                    ......
                    max( case when rn = N then radar_id end ) as routeN */
                FROM (
                    select t.*,
                           row_number() over (
                               partition by date_trunc('day', datetim ),car_id 
                               order by datetim 
                           ) as rn
                    from table111 t
                ) x
                GROUP BY date_trunc('day', datetim ), car_id
        ) x
        group by concat(route1, '>', route2, '>', route3, '>', route4)
) x
GROUP BY route
order by avg( cnt ) desc
LIMIT 2
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53c7e/27

```
|        route | average |
|--------------|---------|
|    A21>B15>> |       3 |
| A21>B15>C09> |       2 |
```

Comment: The result for `A21>B15>C09` is not clear. Why it's 2? There is only one such route on `2017-03-08` and one one `2017-03-09`.